# Is the chrome devtools doc wrong about the Dominator concept in memory analysis?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

https://developers.google.cn/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/memory-101#dominators

This is the first time I'm exposed to this concept. After some study, I can understand it now. But when I head back to the doc, what's documented looks pretty confusing to me.

1. What the heck is "Dominator objects are comprised of a tree structure because each object has exactly one dominator. "? From my understanding, an object can possibly have multiple dominators.
2. Besides, the description to the diagram below says Node 2 dominates nodes 3, 4, and 6. But isn't Node 2 dominating all nodes but node 1?

I just need someone in the know to confirm this because I can't imagine such awful information in the google doc.

Comment: Dominator means the immediate "parent" on the graph.

Comment: @wOxxOm Not really. An immediate parent is not necessarily a dominator because an object can have multiple  immediate parents. Moreover, let's assert your statement is true, then Node 2 is not the immediate parent of Node 6, thus not a dominator of Node 6.

Comment: How about "either the immediate parent if there are no other parents, or the closest single ancestor"?

Comment: @wOxxOm That is called immediate dominator. You may want to check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Memory/Dominators.

Comment: It doesn't contradict my interpretation AFAICT. An immediate dominator is simply a subtype of dominators.

Comment: Ah, everything suddenly clicks into place now. Maybe at least they should make it clear that they are talking about immediate dominators.@wOxxOm